# How do we breed cats that can talk?

Tags: science-based, biology, evolution

Are you fed up with never being sure precisely what your furry companion is pestering you for?

Using selective breeding techniques & (initially at least) ignoring any changes to brain structures that may be indicated to take full advantage (such as increasing the size of areas associated with speech & vocal communication in humans and other animals).

Which physical structures do we need to modify if we wanted to selectively breed cats physically capable of intelligible speech, what would we select for in what order?

Comment: I don't think you can get this through selective breeding. Not on any non-geological time scale.

Comment: We're not talking about one major change. We're not even talking about a series of changes. We're talking about a system of changes, some of which are not obviously evident in the early stages.

Comment: Even if you ignore neurology, this would be like trying to breed the beaks out of birds. Look up why humans can choke on their own food. That's one of the consequences of us being able to talk compared to other animals.

Comment: @DKNguyen Breeding the beaks out of birds can be done in four generations or less if you have just one with the required debilitating mutation to start with, which is probably not that hard to come by to be honest, that if anything is an easier proposition than the one I'm making, suggestive that you don't really know the subject  but as I already said, if you're sure go ahead and do a frame challenge answer 

Comment: Good luck surviving through that mutation. I assume the objective *is* to get a working animal.

Comment: @DKNguyen You're the one that proposed a non working animal I simply ran with it  nothing in mine that would mean it was non working.

Comment: Then you missed why I pointed out the choking aspect earlier.

Comment: @user535733 it's a first things first scenario, a lot easier to measure how well you're doing with the neurological and any intelligence related stuff if you already have the physical ability to talk locked in.

Comment: @DKNguyen so put it in an answer then  because it sounds like you have one, which bits need changing, and the associated problems you perceive (which just boils down to other changes needed to avoid fatality from the primary changes)  going back to your first comment, you do realise that I never asked for anything to happen in a 'reasonable time frame' right?  how long it would take is a whole other question and you know how this site hates people asking multiple questions in one 

Comment: Who cares. They're all jerks anyway.

Comment: Cats already talk. They just have nothing to say to you and refuse to speak.

Comment: What about starting with a human, and gene splicing cat dna in. Or giving a cat a huge brain and teaching it cat sign language (tail head and paw movements etc.)

Comment: Actually cats do talk but with heavy accent ;D

Answer (score 2):

**Physical equipment**

When cats mew, they release controlled puffs of air from their lungs through their larynx so the vocal chords vibrate, making the sound. It means that physical equipment is present.

To talk, cats need flexibility in the mouth, tongue and lips that will let them form a wide range of precise sounds. This may also be present.

**Broca’s area and Brodmann area 47**

But the most important thing is the brain's processing power. The Broca’s area in the cerebrum of human brain is closely associated with speech comprehension. Broca’s area is more than 6 times larger in humans than chimpanzees. Also Brodmann area 47, a nearby patch of brain, is important for extracting meaning from words. Brodmann area 47 has been implicated in the processing of syntax in spoken and signed languages, and more recently in musical syntax.

To make cats talk, increase the

- overall size of brain
- processing power of brain
- Broca’s area
- Brodmann area 47

Comment: @Pelinore I changed my answer.

Answer (score 1):

### Physiology already comes quite close

Q: *"if we wanted to selectively breed cats physically capable of intelligible speech, what would we select for in what order?"*

**Physiological challenges**

The vocal tract system, that is vocal chords, nasal cavity and mouth cavity shape is moved around by certain muscles, to produce the sounds of speech. These sounds are called phonemes. The animal does not need to produce all phonemes, it should sound familiar and recognizable.

There's a lot already in place: cat is a mammal, a cat has a mouth cavity and vocal chords comparable to humans, except it is scaled down. A cat is equipped with accurate muscle control, there will be no issue with bending vowels (we all know how that sounds)

But to produce actual phonemes and let humans comprehend these phonemes, a cat may be too small. As a result of mouth size and vocal chords size, its frequencies are too high up. As for the vocal chords, I did hear cats produce low pitch sounds at night, but these sounds are associated with stress and fights with other cats. Cats would need to learn (or train) when these sounds are appropriate in the house. Also, cats have continuous vowels, it can go like "meiauw", while the human speech requires them to produce discrete vowels. It may help to select kittens that produce "hicky" or "stuttering" sounds rather than long mews.

Breeding:

- To overcome the high pitch issue, it would help to breed bigger cats, or cats with a bigger head.
- if you want your cat to properly control the muscles involved, make sure you select your cats for intelligence!
- Enlarging the brain by breeding is not easy, the skull always lags behind such measures, resulting in pressure and head aches. One option may be a trick: breed *bad eyes* in cats. Gradually, they will loose more eyesight - not needed in the home anyway - and free up more of their brain for listening and speech production.

**Only words and mimicking**

Look at parrots. They can make sounds resembling speech, they can mimic utterances. But still, they need to hear an example. Your cat will too, it will mimic your speech, rather than talk spontaneously.

Breeding:

- Breed social cats, not solitary cats. *Smart* cats, *responsive* cats.
- Focus on variability. Breed cats that tend to make many different sounds.

The rest.. will be up to the cat's owner. When the owner is prepared to invest time, play with the cat, learn the cat to associate certain  sounds with certain situations. Not unlike mothers do, with toddlers. Chance is, your pet will pick up the associations and produce speech-like sounds, instead of mewing.

Comment: ***"centuries of breeding and training"*** I'd have to dispute that, the adjustments that can be made to a species with less than two years to breeding maturity in just a single human lifetime is significant, case in point the [the Belgium Blue](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belgian_Blue&ved=2ahUKEwjxpKW0i9T2AhUbilwKHTBIB6QQmhN6BAgIEAI&usg=AOvVaw3D3sVJxqXQ625ESm1iLUpR) was first developed in the 1800s & the modern breed we know today in the 1950s, so, we might say it took only a decade or (most) conservative only 150 years.

Comment: ***"training"*** training is irrelevant to the question, has nothing to do with it, l only asked which physical traits (albeit mostly internal, or at least semi internal, structures) do we need to breed for.

Comment: @Pelinore no training ? what do you want your cat to say to you ? (if you declare training not to be applicable here I'm afraid I'll have to put a frame challenge instead.. you can't breed "talking cat" like you would breed a cat with different color or size)

Comment: ***Want?***  nothing, it would be more a case of curiosity about what it *would* say (if anything at all) if it could than *want* it to say anything particular  but we diverge from the question there  *why* someone wants this is character motivation and decisions, off topic for the site & l'm not asking about that 

Comment: @Pelinore I was not asking about the "why", my question was "what" you expect from your talking cat. Maybe you could breed a cat to make human-like speech sounds.. but could that be qualified as "talking" ? Maybe this is a English-issue on my side, but I would qualify the term "talking" as using speech to express language. If you expect random speech sounds, my answer could be simplified considerably. But even so, you won't be able to achieve that iwithout affecting the brain in any way. Face muscles involved in making speech sounds need to receive commands from the brain, in order to move.

Comment: And the answer is as above, I'd expect nothing, but I would however be curious to see if given the physical apparatus to talk it then said anything, even one word demands like "food!" would be interesting.

Comment: Well it could ask for food, or ask to open the door. It could greet you when you come home from work. You could attempt to learn your cat to say "hello". But to be successful, your cat still needs to have the means to pronounce the phonemes. Breeding implies selection of properties. What properties need to be selected is your choice. You'll have to listen to the sounds kitties make and select the kitties that approach human speech frequency range. Select the big ones. Or you could select kitties that mew something resembling "hello".

Comment: ***"What properties need to be selected is your choice"*** no, that's wrong, to be able to make approximations of the vowels and consonants we use will require specific structures and modifications to existing ones they don't currently possess, there's no 'authors choice' in that at all.

Comment: @pelinore you can state I'm wrong, but as said in my answer, the basic physiology is already present: cats are mammals, they have vocal chords.. they can modulate their mouth cavity to produce a range of different vowels. They have lips, there is a tongue, they have a nose and nasal cavity properly connected. I think if you look at the building plan of a cat's head compared to dogs, it will be more difficult for dogs to pronounce vowels. Consonants are a matter of friction and aspiration, it requires certain surfaces and muscles to act in a certain way. This is where the training comes in.

Comment: ***"you can state I'm wrong"*** on this point?  you're right! I can & I will, do you want me to say it again?  you can't *train* lips or a tongue to do things they're not designed for & are physically incapable of.

Comment: @Pelinore imho you overestimate the work to be done on the cat's mouth. It will work fine, for a lot of phonemes. The issue is 10% physiology and 90% brain. Producing speech (even without language abilities) involves the brain, and you can't "breed" brain content, you can only breed to enlarge the brain, which will be needed.. the rest is training.

Comment: Your 90% is still outside the scope of the question, I've specifically only asked about the 10% //  Off topic aside / musing: if this was for some real world experiment then the purpose (or point of interest) could very well be (if anything) to test how much of that 90% already exists in cats.

Comment: @Pelinore I finished my edits, removed references to language. But I could not remove everything involving the brain and training.. Even a parrot has to be trained to produce speech, your breeding alone will *not* cause your cat to "talk".